# Nodejs import trouble

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module

For uni I've got this project where I need to make a website with a server. The fonder looks like this:

```
.
├── HTML/
│   └── ...
├── JS/
│   ├── jsfile.js
│   └── ...
└── Nodejs/
    └── nodefile.js
```

In this `jsfile` we have classes defined which we would like to use in `nodefile`> how would we import these classes?

We tried to use require, but then we get errors regarding the fact that we have this in the jsfile:

```
export {
  class1,
  class2
}

module.export.Class = class1;
```

node does not recognise the `export { ... }`, and throws an error

and using `import` and `require` statements simultaneously in node gives errors aswell. So how do we import the classes from the jsfile without interfering with the imports and exports between js files?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `import` syntax when you have `"type": "module"` in the package.json. If not, you should use the `require` syntax

Having both require and import statements are generally not recommended and not best practice but yes there is a way.

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

With this you could use require as such:

```
const data = require("./data.json");
```

More info of that can be found [here](https://www.kindacode.com/article/node-js-how-to-use-import-and-require-in-the-same-file/)

Again, this is not recommended, I suggest that you either stick with `require` or stick with `import` all the way